# Zend Framework: Method after controller action, but before view rendered

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to Zend framework and can't find a clear answer on this. I essentially want some code to execute *after* a controller's logic for a page, but before the layout and view are rendered.

For example, I want to auto-refresh the flash messages and provide them to the layout/view automatically, so that I don't need to do so in every controller. This obviously needs to happen after the controller code has executed since it might add messages.

```
$this->view->messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();
```

Comment: What do you mean by auto-refresh the flashMessenger? It's always fresh!

Comment: I mean to re-assigned the result of getMessages to the view->messages

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, instead use a view helper to display the flash messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a controller plugin, see http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html. The `postDispatch()` method runs after your controller code but before the page is rendered.

Comment: I had tried postDispatch before reading all the answers here and it seems to be working properly. I wanted confirmation that it ran when I believed it did, thanks!

Comment: This isn't working for me. The view is already rendered by the time my code runs in postDispatch() assigning variables to view.

Answer (score 0):

I just use:

```
public function init()
{
    if ($this->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->hasMessages()) {
        $this->view->messages = $this->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->getMessages();
    }
}
```

I use this in `init()` and it works fine. You could use it in `postDispatch()`, `preDispatch()` or `dispatchLoopShutdown()` if you like. A [controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) would not be out of line, I just haven't gotten around to doing one yet.